# Query about the event loop of Nodejs

Tags: node.js, event-loop

It is well known that Nodejs is handling all events in the background loop. But how can I monitor all the active events and is it potential risk of out of memory or dead lock?

Comment: what do you mean by "active events". Are you referring to event handlers?

Comment: Yes, the executing event handlers.

Comment: I have written a simple nodejs request for internet checking and active handles are increasing drastically

Answer (score 0):

- Monitor events:

You can write a log on each event. If you need more, store them into a database.

- Potential risk of out of memory:

Monitor the memory usage of your node process while doing tests. Do stress/load test with ApacheBench (or Node!). In depth: [Debugging node.js memory leaks](http://dtrace.org/blogs/bmc/2012/05/05/debugging-node-js-memory-leaks/)

- Dead lock:

I think you are on your own for this one.